Modify the values in a (global) list of dictionary without reference
I'm new to python - being an educator trying to write to python script to score student's performance downloaded from an online polling platform. I've solved most problems until something like this: I'm trying to copy the values of test1 into test2 without reference and then change the values in test2. I'd like test2 to be available globally for other function calls.
test1=[{'a':1, 'b':2,'c':3},{'a':4, 'b':5,'c':6}]
test2=[]
def CopyList(test1,test2):
import copy

test2 =copy.deepcopy(test1)  

test2[0]['d']= 4

print(test2)

CopyList(test1,test2)
... [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}, {'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 6}]
(so far so good!)
print(test1)
...[{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 6}]
(as desired, nice)
print(test2)
..[]
(it appears that the original test2 was not modified?)
I have also tried d.copy() or list slicing ([:]).  These two methods appear to continue to reference back to the original list (test1) that would get modified.  In no case is test2 modified outside of the function.
I have also tried the (for loop) method:
test1=[{'a':1, 'b':2,'c':3},{'a':4, 'b':5,'c':6}]
test2=[]
def CopyList(test1,test2):
ndict=len(test1)

test2.clear()

for i in range(ndict):

    test2.append(test1[i])

test2[0]['d']= 4

print(test2)

This method produced these results --
print(test1)
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}, {'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 6}]
(how did test1 get modified??)
print(test2)
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}, {'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 6}]
(OK, that is what I wanted)
Any suggestion on how to fix this problem is appreciated.

When passing test2 as an argument to your function it is the same object as your global variable. But you create a new variable and overwrite the old one when you assign test2 = copy.deepcopy(test2). This variable is in a different scope than the global one and no longer the same as the global one. Therefore, it can't be accessed globally.
There are two ways to solve this:

You can modify the existing variable:


test2[:] = copy.deepcopy(test2)
This will only change the contents of the list and not create a new one.


You can overwrite test2 in global scope using the global keyword:


def CopyList(test1):
   global test2
   test2 = copy.deepcopy(test1)  

This will make your test2 = [] statement redundant. But you should generally avoid the global keyword, if possible.


Thank yo for this simple solution! I was stumped by this problem for two days. Maybe my problem was too simple to be asked previously.
